# Using audio files with Figma for mobile app, trying Protopie

Tags: mobile-application, audio

We are building a mobile app in the mental health space.

When we started we chose Figma without realising that it doesn’t have audio support. We have a lot of storytelling in our lessons where we want to play audio files. So we are exploring Protopie.

Now we have the following concerns-

1. Should we continue to use Figma for our design and use Protopie for just prototyping- to add animations, interactions and audio to test it out.
2. How will we hand off to software developers with the design in Figma ? Will we provide the audio files separately and tell them these need to run over these many screens etc?
3. Figma question- How to sync audio and the pause, forward, backward, start buttons with other UI elements like lesson progress bar or scrolling text.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Figma is still a better place for static UI design.
2. Yes, the handoff can't be simply done in only Figma or ProtoPie, you  should well-document the user flow and where and how the audio is used.
3. Absolutely, this can be done in ProtoPie. Figma doesn't support logical prototyping, the only way is to fake it!